# Problems with noobs putting my GA code into their sites

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, conflict, spoken-language

I don't mean for the title to be derogatory, but this is a rather frustrating problem, and I'm looking for a good workaround, given a language barrier involved.

I have a site set up for a plugin I wrote, and, rather than use the site's resources to write their own code, I've had people simply rip the code from the samples on the site. Normally, this wouldn't be any issue at all, but they are also taking my Google Analytics instantiation, so my Analytics data is getting very skewed by incorporating visitation data from their websites.

I've been able to contact the English-speaking site owners with little issue. The problem lies in the Japanese language sites that are yanking the code. I have no idea how to ask them to take down the analytics portion.

Long-term, I'm providing a package that streamlines the learning-to-use process, but in the meantime, what can I do about this language barrier? Is there a way around this problem that I haven't thought of?

Comment: An easy solution would be for you to create a new google analytics account.

Comment: Not exactly a palatable idea at that.

Comment: i would think almost all web-developers can understand and write english (more or less - i'm german, my english is bad, but i understand your problem), so why shouldn't the japanese guys? have you already tried to mail to them?

Comment: can't you filter out traffic from the wrong domain?

Comment: @oezi: Check my response to Vicky's suggestion.

Comment: An GA-side solution would be to add a profile filter to your GA account to restrict the reporting to pages with a specified hostname.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could modify the javascript on your pages to only load Analytics if the domain matches your own.

Comment: I like this idea, because it's pretty inert. Admittedly, I'm a bit of a JS noob myself. `window.location.href`?

Comment: +1 -- they'd have to be enough of a noob to copy the code verbatim but savvy enough to modify the code to allow their own domain. Still possible, but much less likely. You might want to put a warning comment on the code as well.

Comment: Thanks bobince. So, in the meantime, what do I do about the code they already have on their site? They're at http://utaruberainbowcamp.com, and don't appear to have a way to e-mail contact.

Answer (score 7):

Two ideas:

1. Don't show your actual GA code on your site. Replace it with some filler code that makes it obvious it's meant to be replaced. Since I'm not sure what your plugin is about I'm not sure how practical this is, but I think there must be a way.
2. Use Google Translate to give foreign users the option to see your page translated into their own language. Google even [offers a tool](http://translate.google.com/translate_tools) to add a "Choose your language" drop-down to any page. (And of course make sure the most important parts of your site are in plain, easily-translated English.)

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Also, building on Greg's solution, if the domain doesn't match your own, you could alert a message telling the implementer to remove the code, a la what [Crockford did with his JSON parser](http://ajaxian.com/archives/doug-crockford-and-the-online-booty-call-saga).

Answer (score 0):

I would contact them in English (using plain language), and at the bottom I would add a version of the same text run through Google Translate - with an apology that it was generated by Google Translate and may not be accurate.

Comment: I had considered the Google Translate route, but here's the site in question: http://utaruberainbowcamp.com/. I don't see a way to contact via e-mail, and the site is mostly imaged Japanese text (no translate).

Comment: @dclowd9901: Hmm, I see. Whois for their domain is no help either. You could try emailing admin@ or webmaster@ , although also I do notice they have a Twitter feed on their page: http://twitter.com/utaruberainbowc ...